# Is ASP.NET GridView data for non-visible columns are stored in viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, select, gridview

If I query `select *` from a MS-SQL table and display only a few data columns (the rest of the columns are either non-visible or non-existent), does the query result sent to the GridView include all of the unused columns's data or the GridView is sent only the data that are going to be displayed.if all the data is sent then whether only those data will be stored in ViewState or all data is stored
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All columns are available for the GridView for display. It now depends on if you want to show some or all. This is obvious when you set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` on your GridView.

The GridView is a presentation object and abstract/extract the information in the underlying datasource e.g.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" ID="GridView1">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Product Name" DataField="ProductName" />
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

From the example above, `ProductName` and `Price` are shown in the GridView but some other columns from your datasource are available e.g. `ProductID` used for `DataKeyNames`

Comment: You are absolutely correct that the data are available. Do you mean the (unused/undisplayed) data are sent to the user whether they are displayed or not? This would be the opposite of @Aquinas answer above.

Comment: Yes the data are sent. It's not the opposite, just from another angle - ViewState. When you don't display it in the GridView, it is not part of ViewState. ViewState contains information about all controls that are displayed in your page and their state so that when you post back, the same information is retrieved to re-display your page. You can have some data in Session, Cookie and available to user, that does not mean they are in ViewState

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous. Do you mean if you don't show or define the columns that are included in the dataset, does the `ViewState` size still increase as if they were shown? If that's what you're asking, then the answer is no. You can have a DataTable, for example, with 100 column, but if you only show 1 of those columns in your GridView, then the `ViewState` size will be the same as if your DataTable only contained that one column.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly what your 2nd sentence states.